# Positioning multiple Excel tables on separate PowerPoint slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am pasting ranges from Excel to Powerpoint as Tables.

The problem is that when I paste the first table, positioning works fine (.Top and .Left) but the tables I paste after the first one get positioned relative to the first table.

The .Top becomes the distance between the upper left corner of the table and the upper side of the first table's position (not to the upper side of the slide, as it should be!) and the same thing happens to .Left (it represents the distance between the upper left corner of the table and the left side of the first table).

The code is the following:

```
Sub ExportaraPowerPoint()

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim excelTable As Excel.Range
Dim SlideTitle As String
Dim SlideText As String
Dim SlideObject As Object
Dim pptTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim SlideNumber As String
Dim xlTable As PowerPoint.Shape

'Check is PPT is open and create if not
On Error Resume Next
Set pptApp = GetObject("", "PowerPoint.Application")
Err.Clear
If pptApp Is Nothing Then Set pptApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.Activate

'Add presentation
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
pptPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
pptPres.ApplyTemplate "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033\Blank.potx"

'Assing Tables
Set excelTable1 = Worksheets("TDSACI").Range("N246:U259")
Set excelTable2 = Worksheets("TDCSD").Range("N215:U223")

'Slide 1:
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
excelTable1.Copy
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteDefault)
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 670.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Height = 292
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 24.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 90.4

'Slide 2:
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
excelTable2.Copy
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteDefault)
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 670.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Height = 292
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 24.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 90.4
```

I know that the table is always the Shape Index number 2, so that is not a problem.

According to numbers, the position of both tables should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious. If you comment out the **On Error Resume Next**, make sure the VBE is set to **Break on All Errors** in **Options**, put a break at the first Slide 2 line, you'll see that the code quits after the .PasteSpecial line but without generating an error. I think this is because PowerPoint is complaining that slide 2 is not in view so the paste method is getting messed up, even if the object appears to be pasted on the slide! I fixed it on my demo deck (PowerPoint 2016) by adding the GotoSlide method:

```
'Slide 2:
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
excelTable2.Copy
pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteDefault)
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 670.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Height = 292
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 24.4
pptSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 90.4
```

Manipulating the PowerPoint View isn't necessary to paste objects to slides if the code is running in the PowerPoint VBE so I'm not sure what's going wrong in this case.

Comment: one question: i copied the On Error Resume Next from a page online (im new at VBA so i dont understand that much) , do you think it is really necessary ? thanks

Comment: What that does is tell VBA to ignore all errors. It's quite bad programming practice to use it (without a very good reason such as deliberate error trapping) as it can lead to (a) masking errors when developing (b) unexpected behaviour in the real world. It's much better to use an error handler like On Error Goto errorhandler and have an anchor at the end of your code errorhandler:

Comment: If you have permission to do so, don't forget to upvote the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Thanks. I  upvoted, and it got recorded but isnt shown for voters with less than 15 points of reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code to replace the section from `'Assing tables` down might be better (and more scalable) if you're looking to deal with more than 2 ranges..

```
'Assing Tables

Dim excelTables(1) As Range

Set excelTables(0) = Worksheets("TDSACI").Range("N246:U259")
Set excelTables(1) = Worksheets("TDCSD").Range("N215:U223")

For Each myTable In excelTables

    myTable.Copy

    With pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
        .Select
        With .Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault)
            .Width = 670.4
            .Height = 292
            .Left = 24.4
            .Top = 90.4
        End With
    End With

Next
```

Comment: im working with a lot of ranges (47 now and will be more) but not all of them have the same sizes and position. How would you code a size and position from tables 1 to 10 , and another for tables 11 to 20 , for example? thanks. Also, why do you dim exceltables(1) ? why use the index number 1 if you have also cero? thanks again.

Comment: `Dim excelTables(1)` creates an array to hold 2 items, numbered 0 and 1. `Dim excelTables(4)` would create an array to hold 5 items, 0,1,2,3 and 4. I could've used `Dim excelTables(1 to 2)` which now I look at it would've closer matched your original code.

Comment: Why not create a table in your spreadsheet has columns - `sheetname`, `rangeaddress`, `width`, `height`, `left` and `top`. You could then write a macro that reads and processes each of these table 'rows'. That way if you add a new table, it's a simple task to add a row.